# insert text into heredoc from within a shell script (Bash)

Tags: bash

im currently writing tests for a cbor en-/de-coder and i'm using a cli tool called [cbor-diag](https://crates.io/crates/cbor-diag-cli) to create the check values.
however its a lot to constantly write the whole command when throughout all the runs the only value that changes is the value to decode/encode.
my idea was to write a script that automagically inserts the value to en-/de-code.

the problem seems to be that the cli tool uses a heredoc for the variable, which i cant insert into.
the errormessage is :
"/opt/cbor_dec: line 7: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
/opt/cbor_dec: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
 then
   echo "no args passed"
 else
   variable="$1 END"
   cbor-diag --to bytes <<-END ${variable}|xxd
 fi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
also im a complete noob with bash scripting...

UPDATE:

as a commenter suggested i could use heredoc syntax, hoewever this leads to the same errormessage.
updated code:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "no args passed"
else
    cbor-diag --to bytes <<-END | xxd
    ${1}
    END
fi
```

UPDATE 2:
as commenter suggested the spaces infront of the END delimiter were the problem!
updated code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "no args passed"
    exit 1
fi
cbor-diag --to bytes <<-END | xxd
${1}
END
```

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed a heredoc delimiter in a variable without relying on hacky tools like `eval` (and maybe not even that). Heredocs are evaluated at a similar time as things like command substitutions, which happens before variables expand.

But, there's also no reason to embed it in the variable here. Normal heredoc syntax will do the job.

```
variable=$1
cbor-diag --to bytes <<-END | xxd
${variable}
END
```

Comment: i tried it the way you described, however i still get the same errormessage...

Comment: Your edited example has leading spaces in front of the delimiter which isn't allowed. Since you're using `<<-END` you could put leading tabs, but not spaces.

Comment: do you mean the indentation in the line with END? ill try and let you know soon...
EDIT: it was the indentation! thank you very much!!